# twig symfony php application working in wamp loacal machine but not in live hosting

Tags: php, symfony, twig, composer-php

I have created application youtube downloader by using `youtube-dl`, `twig`, `symfony.composer`

In WAMP local machine working fine.

But I deployed to live hosting : showing 500 error

I found this error

> class 'twig_loader_filesystem' not found in init.php

path to twig engine
domain.com/vendor/twig/twig

File Tree (screenshot)
[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyw8C.png)

MY init.php code

```
<?php
session_start();

require "vendor/autoload.php";
require "classes/Processor.php";
require "classes/Abstractor.php";
use Noodlehaus\Config;
use myPHPnotes\Processor;
use myPHPnotes\Abstractor;

//Abstractor
$abstractor = new Abstractor;

// Configuration
$config = new Config(__DIR__ . '/../config/' . file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../mode.php') . '.php');

//Processor
$processor = new Processor($config);

// Twig View
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../views/');

//$loader = new Twig_loader_Filesystem('views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('config', $config);
```

am ditching my head from 1 week please any help from stackoverflow team

Thank you

Comment: did you try `\Twig_Loader_Filesystem ` ? I mean adding a backslash

Comment: yes @BenoitNgô no luck :( anywayys thanks for the reply

Comment: its probably a path issue, can you show your file tree on your "live-host"?

Comment: domain.com/vendor/twig/twig

Comment: I mean, the path on your machine. Is init.php at `/var/www/html/init.php`? Where is vendor? Where is `views`? Did you composer install on the host? whats the version of twig installed?

Comment: oh sorry this is the path on machine wamp\www\hdbuddy\initialization\init.php    path to view wamp\www\hdbuddy\views  and  i have installed composer on local machine just uploaded all files to hosting

Comment: I guess your machine is on linux, and your local is on window.
Can you composer remove your vendor on the "live-host" and `./composer.phar install` on the "live-host"

Comment: I mean just remove the `vendor` directory

Comment: i am using twig as a template engine if i remove vendor twig also removed not working

Comment: i followed this everything same..but as per video his domain is working not mine  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Mb0ah-7cJM&list=PLC-R40l2hJffoF6QLVj-0FexFWA-mcWOo&index=16

Comment: whats your domain?

Before i was talking about:
1) Remove your vendor on the "live-host"
2) Do `composer install` on the "live-host"

Comment: I think this is an environment related problem, are you hosted on a linux or a windows machine?

Comment: linix cpanel vps hosting

Comment: everything done as per video server requirements everything ok same script.

Comment: on cpanel, there is command line tool, if i remember correctly, can you use it to remove vendor and launch composer install via cli? for this you can `cd` to your composer.json path and `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar && chmod 774 composer.phar && ./composer.phar install`

Comment: nice got homepage.. but when i enter youtube url showing 500 error http://brsnsriram.com

Comment: maybe rights issues, without error i can not tell you. Did you get the homepage following my instruction?

Comment: yes got homepage

Comment: but when i enter youtube url getting this in error long

Comment: [12-Apr-2018 17:47:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) in /home/brsnsriram/public_html/classes/Processor.php on line 51

Comment: code :  $process->run();
  if(!$process->isSuccessful()){

   $error = $process->getErrorOutput();
    throw new \Exception("Error Processing Request", $error, 1);
   }
   else{

    return trim($process->getOutput());
   }
    
 }

Comment: the script do not work ? Maybe something is not installed.
can you `error_log( $process->getErrorOutput());` just after `$process->run()`

Comment: fixed that also now when i run url showing this error '/home/brsnsriram/public_html/youtube-dl' '-4' '--' 'dump-single-json' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntFFQmYbhUk'/home/brsnsriram/public_html/youtube-dl -4 -- dump-single-json https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntFFQmYbhUkbool(false) string(292) "WARNING: Assuming --restrict-filenames since file system encoding cannot encode all characters. Set the LC_ALL environment variable to fix this. ERROR: u'dump-single-json' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run youtube-dl "ytsearch:dump-single-json" )

Comment: its a warning... its write, encoding issues